# Elasticsearch aggregation shows incorrect total

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Elasticsearch version is 7.4.2

I suck at Elasticsearch and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this query.

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "firstName"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "fields": [
              "params.display",
              "params.description",
              "params.name",
              "lastName"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "DONE"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "success": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "createDate": "desc"
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "lastName.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "lastChange",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "createDate": "desc"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "lastName.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "total": {
            "value": 429896
        }
    }
```

So ~430k results, but in pagination we stop getting results around the 426k mark. Meaning, when I run the query with

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 427000,
...
}
```

I get:

```
{
    "took": 2215,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "total": {
            "value": 429896
        }
    }
}
```

But if I change `from` to be 426000 I still get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the cardinality aggregation value of your field `lastName.keyword` to your total documents in the index, which is two different things.

You can check the total no of documents in your index using the [count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) and from/size you are defined at query level ie it brings the documents matching your search query and as you don't have `track_total_hits` it shows `10k` with relation `gte` means there are more than `10k` documents matching your search query.

When it comes to your aggregation, I can see in both the case it returns the count as `429896` as this aggregation is not depend on the from/size you are mentioning for your query.

Comment: Yeah after playing around with the count api, I think that this makes more sense to use than the aggregation. The only problem that I see is that the count api doesn't support collapse, so the count will still be off from my actual query. Any advice there would be appreciated.

Comment: @TutanRamen,  sorry for delay in response, reg collapse i need to do some research, i would suggest to ask a follow up question, and pls mark it as answer as it gave the answer to your question you ask:)

Comment: @TutanRamen, did you get a chance to ask followup question? Also would be great if you can mark answer as it solved your query asked in question.

Comment: Well, we went a different direction. Instead of doing this aggregation we decided to split the data into it's own table so we could more easily query it.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised when I found out that the cardinality parameter has [Precision control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_precision_control).

Setting the maximum value was the solution for me.